# How to remove unwanted newline returned from using base64.b64encode

Tags: python, csv, base64, newline

I am using the base64 to encode a binary image file.

```
with open("33111117789.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

I am expecting it to return a bytes object without newlines based on the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode

However, there are several unexpected newlines returned after I exported them into csv file.

```
# Update to csv
dateNow = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
data = ["1", dateNow, "+33111117789", encoded_string]

with open('output.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Here is the result:
[image]

By right, it should be only a single line result, but it returns in multiple new lines.

Am I using wrong base64 python function? Have I missing out some of the parameters? Thanks!

I have tried using base64.encode() and base64.b64encode(), but both of them returned the same - unexpected newlines.

One thing I noticed is on every newline, there is the plus sign '+' in front of the newline, is the '+' sign expected? Or should I remove it?
[Image of '+' sign on every starting newlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY7GJ.png)

Comment: The problem lies with the `encoded_string` being `bytes` and not a `str`, which csv writer expects.  The tell is that the `b'...` is shown in the output.  Try actually turning that into a `str` (e.g. `data = [..., encoded_string.decode('ascii')]`) before feeding it to the csv.writer.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster, thanks for suggestion! I have try added `[..., encoded_string.decode('ascii')]`, but still seeing the same result.

I have also tried to remove the newline - '\n' but still resulted the same.
`[..., encoded_string.decode('ascii').replace("\n", "")]`

One thing I noticed is on every newline, there is the plus sign '+' in front of the newline, is the '+' sign expected? Or should I remove it? Note: I have uploaded the sample data output in my question on top.

Comment: That's because the `'\n'` is never present, `base64.encode()` and `base64.b64encode()` both don't add `'\n'` to the output. The error is purely in how the program displayed the very long lines - try resizing the window and you might be able to see the lines change.  I have also tried to reproduce your issue and could not, verify the output file yourself by counting how many lines are in the file, e.g. `len(open('output.csv').readlines())` should return `1`.  The error has to do with how the GUI program display the text, try resizing the window.

Comment: Moreover, the `+` character starting every line is simply how your GUI program auto-wrapping on symbol characters when it encounters very long lines.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster, yes, you are right! Indeed when I count how many lines in the csv file, it returns 1. Also, I have tried to open the csv file using notepad++, and it managed to show in one single line.

So, do you mean that it depends on what GUI program we are using to open that file? Is there any settings that we can change to workaround this?

Comment: Consult the documentation of the program you are using.